# Android studio not showing when I create new project

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

When I start a new project, Android Studio is showing on Windows TaskBar, but I can't make it show up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try hovering on the icon on the taskbar, then right click on the preview, then click *Maximize*.

Comment: i have been uninstall and make clear all directory related ,but thx for answering :"D